# Mostrar los planes de suscripción antes de abrir la página del producto o el carrito de compra

Tags: woocommerce

Estoy usando el plugin Woo Product Table Pro para mostrar mis productos en tablas. La mayoría de ellos son simples
productos con planes de suscripción (mensual y anual) y muestran sus precios en una columna llamada
"Precios". Pero en esta columna sólo muestra los precios iniciales de los productos.
Por ejemplo: Desde: $500 /mes . Quiero que se muestren en esta columna los dos planes de suscripción
planes de suscripción en lugar de eso. De lo contrario, el usuario tiene que añadir el producto a la cesta o hacer clic en el
producto para abrir su página y luego seleccionar el plan.

Además, una vez que el usuario selecciona sus productos quiero que se restrinja a comprar sólo productos
con el mismo plan. Es decir, si seleccionó un producto con un plan mensual sólo permitir comprar
productos con ese tipo de plan.

Creo que este tema está relacionado con el core de woocommerce no con el plugin que estoy usando para mostrar
las tablas, porque muestra el mismo texto con los productos en la página de la tienda o los productos relacionados.
Entonces, ¿hay alguna forma de cambiar esto?

Este es el link de mi página: https://oblako.com.mx/paquetes-de-negocio/

Agradecería su ayuda o sugerencias.

Gracias

Comment: Todo es posible, sin embargo, en este caso si necesitaras un plugin personalizado, lo primero es verificar si existe un plan activo, luego segun el plan activo hacer lo que quieres, ocultar o mostrar un producto basado en su plan, se me ocurren muchas formas de hacerlo sin embargo tendras si o si crear un plugin propio, recomiendo leer sobre el core de woocommerce y aprender php en caso de que no lo sepas o bien contactar a un desarrollador, debido a lo completo del tema no es posible dar una solución concreta a tu problema, por ende te invito a leer [ask].

Comment: @Jefferzon Bol Ok muchas gracias por tu comentario